# AVURLAsset not working iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im syncing the audio and video files using AVURLAsset.Im getting the exported file but only audio is exported and not the video.How to solve this issue.please help me.Thanks in advance.

Im using the code below:

```
moviePlayer = [[VideoPlay alloc]initWithNibName:@"VideoPlay" bundle:nil];


    if(sp==1){
           NSURL *VUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:elements.videoUrl];
        NSURL *AUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:elements.audioUrl1 ];
        NSLog(@"%@--%@",AUrl,VUrl);




        AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:AUrl options:nil];
        AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:VUrl options:nil];

        AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

        AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionCommentaryTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio                                                                                                     preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        [compositionCommentaryTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration) 
                                            ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] 
                                             atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

        AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo                                                                                                preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) 
                                       ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] 
                                        atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

        AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition 
                                                                              presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];   

        NSString *videoName = @"export.m4v";

        NSString *exportPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];
        NSURL    *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:exportPath]) 
        {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportPath error:nil];
        }
         NSLog(@"Export Status %d-- ", _assetExport.status);
        _assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
        NSLog(@"file type %@",_assetExport.outputFileType);
        _assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;
        _assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

        [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(void ) { 

             NSLog(@"hello");
             switch (_assetExport.status) 
             {
                 case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                 {
                     NSLog (@"FAIL %@",_assetExport.error);
                     if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[_assetExport.outputURL path]]) 
                     {
                         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[_assetExport.outputURL path] error:nil];
                     }

                     //                            // [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector (ritenta)
                     //                                                    withObject:nil
                     //                                                 waitUntilDone:NO];
                     break;
                 }
                 case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: 
                 {

                     //                            // [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector (saveVideoToAlbum:)
                     //                                                    withObject:exportPath
                     //                                                 waitUntilDone:NO];
                     break;
                 }
                 case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled: 
                 {
                     NSLog (@"CANCELED");

                     break;
                 }
             }
             NSLog(@"Export Status %d-- %@", _assetExport.status, _assetExport.outputURL);
             if(_assetExport.status==3){
                moviePlayer.videolink = _assetExport.outputURL;
                 [self presentModalViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES];    
                 [moviePlayer readyPlayer];
             }

            }


         ];                
           }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Simplify your code to the [smallest working sample](http://sscce.org/) that shows the problem.
2. Check the return errors.
3. Try a different export preset instead of `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough`.

Comment: Please tell if it is for iphone

Comment: You mean the export presets? Yes, they work on the iPhone. I’m not sure if all of them, but `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` works for me.

Comment: Sorry, I have no sample code ready and don’t have the time to write it for you. Simplify your current code and try a different export preset. That’s the best advice I can give.

Comment: while trying this code its showing me ExportSessionError: The requested URL was not found on this serve any suggestion to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Try a different export preset instead of AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough
and NSString *videoName = @"export.mp4" instead of   NSString *videoName = @"export.m4v";